# Create New Columns from Row Values then Group By

Tags: sql, count, rows

My current table looks like this:

```
+-------+------+
| Level | Team |
+-------+------+
|     1 |    1 |
|     2 |    1 |
|     2 |    1 |
|     3 |    2 |
|     3 |    2 |
|     3 |    2 |
+-------+------+
```

I want to group by level and know the count of level for both teams. I can easily get the count of a single team by using the following:

```
SELECT Level, Count(Team)
FROM table
WHERE Team = 1
GROUP BY Level
SORT BY Level;
+-------+-------------+
| Level | Team1_Count |
+-------+-------------+
|     1 |           1 |
|     2 |           2 |
|     3 |           0 |
+-------+-------------+
```

However, the end result I want is below:

```
+-------+-------------+-------------+
| Level | Team1_Count | Team2_Count |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
|     1 |           1 |           0 |
|     2 |           2 |           0 |
|     3 |           0 |           3 |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

Removing the WHERE clause gives the total per Level but does not split it into Teams. How do I make it so both of these new columns are created and show the counts per Level?

Comment: which sql engine you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following using `case` expression with `sum`. Here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ekLdPVkyDvxfdXVM5HbEGv/1).

```
select
  level,
  sum(case when team = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Team1_count,
  sum(case when team = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Team2_count
from table
group by
  level
order by
  level
```

output

```
| level | Team1_count | Team2_count |
| ----- | ----------- | ----------- |
| 1     | 1           | 0           |
| 2     | 2           | 0           |
| 3     | 0           | 3           |
```

if you are using postgreSQL then you can use `filter` with `count` as following

```
select
  level,
  count(*) filter (where team = 1) as Team1_count,
  count(*) filter (where team = 2) as Team2_count
from tableA
group by
  level
order by
  level
```